# What's the best way to send HTTP if Content-Length is only approximate?

Tags: http

I wrote a CGI program to send a large blob of dynamically generated data over HTTP. However, I don't know the *exact* content length in advance.

I can't store the whole response in memory to count the bytes because the working set is many GB.

Similarly, I can't walk the data in advance of starting the transfer because the transfer takes much longer than the typical timeout of HTTP requests -- it takes a couple of minutes to write the response to `/dev/null`.

I can however guess that the Content-Length within a factor of ~1.5.

So if I send

```
Status: 200 OK
Content-Length: 328
```

Then write a body of length 233, and `close(2)` the socket gracefully, will HTTP clients think it was successful or not?

One data point is that wget seems to send a second request with headers

```
Range: bytes=234-
```

OK  I've prepared for this, and respond

```
Status: 416 Range Not Satisfiable
```

Here's the full wget session (using tiny mock data):

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 328 [text/csv]
Saving to: ‘large_blob’

71% [========================>    ] 233         --.-K/s   in 0.03s   

2015-10-21 09:22:57 (7.31 KB/s) - Connection closed at byte 233. Retrying.

--2015-10-21 09:22:58--  (try: 2)  http://127.0.0.1/large_blob
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

So, wget exits with return code 0 which seems to indicate success -- this is what should happen!

**The question** is: Is this correct, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct. If you do not know the content length in advance, don't send a Content-Length header field. Instead, use chunked encoding. (See RFC 7230 for details)